# How to state correctly the author informations of an article with microdata?

Tags: article, microdata, author, rich-snippets

I'm using the [microdata system for some articles](http://schema.org/Article).
But I can't find some good ressources to know if the structure of my schema, for the author, is good or not.

"Article"'s shema allow to specify an "author", but how to indicate the informations (image, link, name) about this author ?

Actualy I use the following ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zgm6m/1/)):

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Article title</h1>
    <div itemprop="articleBody">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
    <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" class="author">
        <a href="member-page.html" itemprop="url">
          <img itemprop="image" src="http://pic.okisurf.com/member/none/xs/m.png"/>
          <span itemprop="name">Author name</span>            
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does this line is correct ?

```
<div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
```

If it is not, any help or ressource link will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that to specify a new `itemtype` inside another, we need to specify another time the `itemscope` !

So this line will be correct :

```
<div itemscope="" itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
```

To make sure that the microdata are well formed, I suggest to use the [Webmaster Tools richsnippets test](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)